# Allow a default false boolean from database to change once button is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently working on an app in Rails that has users accept/reject requests from other users. I have a boolean in my database, `t.boolean :accepted, :default => false` that has a default value false and I'm trying to have the value change to true if a user clicks the "accept" button.

I know I'm going to have to make a form that will do a POST/PATCH request but i'm unsure on how to change that value.

Comment: This question is too broad to get a complete answer. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Usually it's as easy as `model.accepted = true` and then `model.save` where `model` is an instance of this particular record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I'm going to have to make a form that will do a POST/PATCH
>   request but i'm unsure on how to change that value.

You don't need a *form* here. As you are just trying to update a model instance with a button click, you just need a `link_to` with a `route` that is defined to perform this action. Considering your model is `Request`,the below should work

`<%= link_to "Accept", accept_request_path(request) %>`

Where `request` is the *instance* which need to be updated.

```
#routes.rb
patch /requests/:id/accept, to: requests#accept, as: :accept_request
```

or if you want a *resourceful route*, you can do

```
resources :requests do
  patch 'accept', on: :member
end
```

And in the `requests_controller` have a `accept` method with below code

```
def accept
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])
  @request.update_attribute(accepted: true)
end
```